# Create google maps markers from pixel xy coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to create markers on a google map starting from pixel coordinates, using the code below.    Im trying to use fromDivPixelToLatLng() to convert the pixel xy coordinates into Lat Long, but I can't get any markers to come up.   I need the markers to set on the map without a click event. Can anyone give me some advice?

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var map;
function initialize() {

  var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(10,0),
      zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);

  var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  overlay.draw = function() {};
  overlay.setMap(map);

  var pixelLatLng = overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(200,200));

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      position: pixelLatLng,
      map: map,
      });


};//end initialize

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wait for the map to be initialized (the idle event):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var map;
function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(10,0),
      zoom: 2,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"),mapOptions);

  var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  overlay.draw = function() {};
  overlay.setMap(map);

  google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map,'idle', function() {
    var pixelLatLng = overlay.getProjection().fromDivPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(200,200));

    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: pixelLatLng,
          map: map,
        });
  });
};//end initialize

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```